# Which are the current open problems in solid state physics?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

I am chemist trying to get an idea of which are the trends now in solid state physics and what problems researchers in this area try to solve. I kindly ask you to name the problems that are found more important to be solved in the near future.